# Problemas para pasar las categorías como texto en las fechas para gráficos usando highchart

Tags: python, web2py, highcharts

Estoy utilizando `highchart` en el framework `web2py` para generar gráficos, inicialmente una parte de mi función como controlador era la siguiente:

```
    year = 2016
    month = 4
    dias_totales = calendar.monthrange(year, month)[1]
    categorias = [datetime.date(year, month, day).strftime('%d/%m/%y') for day in range(1, dias_totales+1)]
    series = []
    documentos_por_usuario = {}
    for documento in data:
        usuario = documento.usuarios.nombre
        if  usuario not in documentos_por_usuario:
            documentos_por_usuario[usuario] = [0] * dias_totales
        documentos_por_usuario[usuario][documento.registro.fecha_ingreso.day-1] += 1

    for nombre, cantidades in documentos_por_usuario.items():
        series.append({
            'name': nombre,
            'data': cantidades
        })
```

con la cual generaba un gráfico con los días del mes de abril, ahora lo que deseo es obtener un gráfico con un rango de fechas, con un `form` y una libreria `dateutil` para calcular las fechas,  que el usuario elija osea, que realice el gráfico desde una fecha inicial hasta fecha final; con la cual estoy usando esta función :

```
form = SQLFORM.factory(
        Field('usuario', 'reference usuarios',requires=IS_IN_DB(db, db.usuarios, '%(nombre)s', zero='---- Elegir Opcion ----')),
        Field('desde', 'date'),
        Field('hasta', 'date'),
    )
    rango=[]
    series = []
    data = []
    categorias = []
    if form.process().accepted:
        usuario = form.vars.usuario
        desde = form.vars.desde
        hasta = form.vars.hasta
        dias_totales = (hasta - desde).days
        for days in range(dias_totales + 1):
            fecha = desde + relativedelta(days=days)
            rango.append(fecha)
        if desde is None or hasta is None:
            return

        data = db((db.registro.usuario==usuario) &
                  ((db.registro.fecha_ingreso>=desde) & (db.registro.fecha_ingreso<=hasta))
                  ).select(
            db.usuarios.nombre,
            db.registro.numero_documento,
            db.registro.fecha_ingreso,
            left=(
            db.usuarios.on(db.usuarios.id==db.registro.usuario),
                 )
        )

    documentos_por_usuario = {}
    for documento in data:
        usuario = documento.usuarios.nombre
        if  usuario not in documentos_por_usuario:
            documentos_por_usuario[usuario] = [0] * dias_totales
        documentos_por_usuario[usuario][documento.registro.fecha_ingreso.day-1] += 1
    for nombre, cantidades in documentos_por_usuario.items():
        series.append({
            'name': nombre,
            'data': cantidades
        })
```

Mi problema esta en como estoy pasando `categorias`
ya que inicialmente usaba esto para pasar a categorias los valores como texto en las fechas:

```
categorias = [datetime.date(year, month, day).strftime('%d/%m/%y') for day in range(1, dias_totales+1)]
```

quiero cambiar mi función y meterle a la fecha un `strftime` para formatearla como quiero pero al intentarlo varias veces no estoy obteniendo resultados, cual es la forma correcta?

Comment: Y qué es lo que quieres conseguir? De tu explicación no me queda del todo claro.

Comment: Quería conseguir las fechas de categoria como texto, pero ya lo resolví.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ya lo resolvi, lo que tenia que hacer era usar otra variable y pasarle un `strftime`para luego igualarla a la lista de `categoria`

```
for days in range(dias_totales + 1):
            fecha = desde + relativedelta(days=days)
            letra = fecha.strftime('%d/%m/%y')
            rango.append(letra)
        if desde is None or hasta is None:
            return
        categorias=rango
```

Comment: Si resolviste tu problema con esto, acepta tu respuesta.

Comment: Dice que tengo que esperar 2 días para hacerlo ...